# Custom Option Cart Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, cart, checkout

to everyone !

Someone can help me with my proyect, Is very simple but I have one thing that makes me crazy.

I have this:

[image]

every checkbox have a value (additional value price)

I need change the price wen I checked in one, two or all checkbox and save this options to send it to the checkout and email....And show this options to order information in the back-end.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'custom_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function custom_cart_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( ! is_cart() )
        return $item_name;

    $item_name .= $value3.'<div class="lineList">';
    $value2 = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_preciosCata');
    if( $value1 = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_varArrayTitle') ) {
        for ($i=0;$i<count($value1); $i++) {
            //$item_name .= '<div class="lineOne lorem"><input type="checkbox" name="cart[%s][lorem]" id="addPrice" value="' . $value2[$i] . '"> <span class="custom-field"> ' . $value1[$i] . ' </span></div>';
            $item_name .= sprintf( '<div class="lineOne lorem"><input type="checkbox" id="_checkbox' . $i . '" name="_checkbox' . $i . '" value="' . $value2[$i] . '" class="checkedBox url text" /> <span class="custom-field">' . $value3.$value1[$i] . ' </span></div>', $cart_item_key, esc_attr( $values['url'] ) );
        }
    }
    $item_name .= '</div>';

    return $item_name;
}
```

I update the car here but dont save the value:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'bbloomer_cart_refresh_update_qty' );
function bbloomer_cart_refresh_update_qty() {
    if (is_cart()) {
        ?>
        <script>
            jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', '.checkedBox', function(){
                jQuery("[name='update_cart']").prop("disabled", false);
                jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
                //alert($(this).val());
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

I need help please

Comment: Note: $value3 is not defined in your code…

Comment: $value3 please delete it from the code